# Support Vector Regression vs. Linear Regression

Tags: regression, modeling, svm, linear, example

I am new to ML and I am learning the different algorithms one can use to perform regression. Keep in mind that I have a strong mathematical background, but I am new in the ML field.

So I understand the math behind Support Vector Regression and behind Linear Regression. Now I just want to understand when is it best to use each. I would very much appreciate if you could give some real-life examples on when one works better than the other.

Comment: There’s not really a sharp line between the two -- basis expansion allows linear regression to estimate rich relationships. Moreover, [tag:random-fourier-features] are an example of a linear-in-parameters model that also has connections to popular kernel methods, such as RBF kernel regression.

Comment: Linear regression can use the same kernels used in SVR, and SVR can also use the linear kernel. Given only the coefficients from such models, it would be impossible to distinguish between them in the general case (with SVR, you might get sparse coefficients depending on the penalization, due to $\epsilon$-insensitive loss)

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief (including beliefs implicit in [another answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/633112/247274)), linear regressions can handle extremely complicated relationships between variables, including curves and interactions. In that regard, a linear regression should be able to handle (basically) anything that a seemingly more sophisticated model like a support vector regression can do. To bring some mathematical rigor to this argument, consider the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

A possible drawback to the linear model is that these relationships need to be specified for the linear regression to fit them. If you don't tell the linear model to consider an interaction between variables, for instance, it will not.

For better or for worse, complex machine learning models like support vector regressions (random forests, neural networks, etc) go and figure out these complex relationships on their own. That sounds extremely powerful, and there is a sense it which it absolutely is. However, it also becomes easy to fit to coincidences in the data and find apparent patterns that aren't really there, because the model is so flexible and able to go chase what it think are patterns.

Linear models will be most useful when you have some sense of what relationships matter. If you know to anticipate some nonlinearity, you can use polynomials or, perhaps better yet, splines to allow for curvature. If you anticipate interactions between variables, you can include them. If you anticipate interactions between nonlinear transformations, you can interact polynomials and splines, too. It is also possible to throw a huge amount of flexibility at the model, such as in the Earth/MARS method, possible penalizing with some regularization. In terms of philosophy, however, this is not so different from the more sophisticated machine learning methods like support vector machines

Support vector regressions will be most useful when you do not know what relationships exist between the variables, just that the given variables should be predictive of the outcome (perhaps humans can look at those variables and reliably make accurate predictions, such as speech recognition where speakers of a particular language typically understand each other, based only on the audio signal). Since you are making the model not only figure out the relationship but which relationships to figure out, data requirements increase in order to keep from fitting to coincidences in the training data that cannot be counted on to exist when the model is deployed.

Vanderbilt's Frank Harrell, also a Cross Vallidated [member](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/4253/frank-harrell), has at least two related blog posts worth reading, even if they aren't about support vector machines in particular. This answer reiterates some of his arguments.

[Road Map for Choosing Between Statistical Modeling and Machine Learning](https://www.fharrell.com/post/stat-ml/)

[Musings on Statistical Models vs. Machine Learning in Health Research](https://www.fharrell.com/talk/mlhealth/)

Comment: SVR can also be linear, and linear regression can also use kernels

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line, linear regression is more readily interpreted, however it comes with more assumptions that need to be met when compared with SVR.

Comparing Linear Regression (LR) and Support Vector Regression (SVR):

### Linear Regression (LR):

**Strengths**: LR is a straightforward and efficient method. It's highly interpretable, providing clear coefficients for each feature variable, which can be interpreted as the change in the dependent variable for a one-unit change in that feature. This makes it a good choice when you need to explain the impact of individual variables.
Weaknesses: LR assumes a linear relationship between the variables, which is not always the case in real-world data. It's sensitive to outliers, which can skew the regression line and affect the accuracy of predictions. LR can also be affected by multicollinearity, where two or more predictor variables are highly correlated. This can inflate the variance of the coefficient estimates and make the estimates very sensitive to minor changes in the model.

**Weakness**: The impact of failing to meet assumptions can be significant, and assumptions are often not met for real world data.

### Support Vector Regression (SVR) with a linear kernel:

**Strengths**:

1. ***Robustness***: SVR with a linear kernel is more robust than Linear
   Regression as it doesn't make as many assumptions. For instance, it
   doesn't require the residuals to be normally distributed or
   homoscedastic (having the same variance at each level of the
   independent variables). This makes it more flexible in handling
   different types of data.
2. ***Outlier Insensitivity***: SVR is less sensitive to outliers compared to Linear Regression. This is because SVR tries to fit the best line
   within a certain threshold, focusing on the points that are close to
   the decision boundary (support vectors). This characteristic can be
   particularly useful when dealing with data that contains outliers.
3. ***Flexibility***: Even with a linear kernel, SVR does not strictly assume
   a linear relationship between the independent and dependent
   variables. This allows it to potentially capture more complex
   relationships within the data, even though the function it's trying
   to fit is linear.

**Weaknesses**: It is less interpretable because it doesn't provide clear coefficients for each feature.

---

As an example, look at this comparison of models fit by SVR with linear kernel and linear regression for noisy linear-ish data. $X$ is drawn from uniform distribution $[0,5)$. $Y = \frac{1}{1+e^-X}$ with random uniform $[-1.5, 1.5]$ noise added to 20% of values. Note that we still have an inappropriate choice of model here, the intent here is to show what might happen if we dont meet assunptions for LR and how SVM might pull ahead in such a case.

[image: a comparison of models generated by SVR with a linear kernel and a linear regression model]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This answer seems to ignore the possibility of nonlinear basis functions in linear regressions, as I discuss in my answer and is discussed in the linked blog posts.

Comment: How would you know the relationship is linear in a multidimensional setting ($p>2$)?

Comment: @Firebug depends, generally I'd say that's a difficult task. A start could be made w/ a scatter-plot matrix when looking at a reasonably low number of dimensions, no?

Comment: @Dave yes, but linear regression is far more sensitive to outliers and unexpected distributions. We could account for distribution as well, but now we are leaving 'linear' linear modelling territory. The point you make does raise the fact I've glossed over the fact that handling non linear data with SVM's does required a non-linear kernel, so I'll update my answer to SVM w/ linear kernal.